# Why is it correct to use ～た in this sentence, even though we're talking about next week?

Tags: tense

This is how we filled in the blank in class, but I am still having a hard time seeing why or how it would be correct. Here is the sentence,

> 来週の日曜日、ほかの学生たちといっしょに先生の家にしょうたい**されました**。

I was thinking that, well, since we are talking about the next week, why would we say され**ました**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tense of the verb 招待{しょうたい}する (to invite) is indicating the time of when the inviting itself happened. The passive form of the verb, 招待される (to get invited), is the same in that respect.

It is the same in English: “We **got** invited to go to our teacher’s house Sunday of next week.”

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I never brought myself to look up the meaning of the word itself before jumping to a conclusion. Thank you for your help and sorry for the trouble.